# SQL Server - What Objects Refer to a Table?

Tags: sql-server

I have table that is possibly used or referred to by other database objects such a view, trigger, stored procedure.

The table is usually inserted into, or updated through a WebFOCUS front-end.

I want to update records in the table directly in the database, but want to determine what database objects will be impacted by a direct update.

What is the best/easiest way to identify those database objects?

Thanks.

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click the table name in the tree-view on the left, and select "Dependencies".

Answer (score 0):

you can use sp_depends to get the list of dependent objects

```
USE YourDBName;  
GO  
EXEC sp_depends @objname = N'schema.Table' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the following

```
use [Your_DB_Name]
select [object_name]=object_name(object_id), [object_schema]=object_schema_name(object_id) 
from sys.sql_modules 
where definition like '%<your_table_name>%'
```

Note: sp_depends does not work in lots of times, such as when a UDF refers to a table, or the table is referred in a dynamic sql.

Comment: This could also miss some things. For example if there is an alias for a table. It is always tough to be 100% bullet proof when discussing dependencies. :)

Comment: Not really, alias is always after a real name, so you will not miss the real name. The only problem with this approach is accuracy, i.e. you will usually get more false alarms, but on the other hand, you will not miss the true objects. For example, if your table is [abc], and you also have a table called [myabc], then [myabc] will also be picked up. To improve accuracy, we can use regular expression but that is a little over-reaching for some quick check.

Comment: I meant to say synonym, not alias.

Comment: that's a good point, Sean. But if that is the case, we should find all synonyms for the table of interest and then change the where clause by adding more OR conditions. :-)

Comment: Agreed. Hence my comment about why it can be so difficult to nail this down 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight your table in query window, then

> Alt + F1